# cakephp hide login url

Tags: url, cakephp, authentication

Since Im using Auth in CakePHP, localhost/mysite/cakephp always redirect to  localhost/mysite/cakephp/users/login.

What Im asking for is a simple way to hide "/users/login" from the url at the startpage.. ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're trying to "hide" the url when people go to login, you could create a route for a different url and use that. Something like:

```
Router::connect('/signon', array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'login');
```

Then in your app_controller set:

```
$this->Auth->loginAction('/signon');
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you need to configure which actions are all allowed for those users who are not logged in.

Assuming 1.3, you'll want the details over here, http://book.cakephp.org/view/1250/Authentication
and http://book.cakephp.org/view/1250/Authentication#!/view/1251/Setting-Auth-Component-Variables

Configure your Auth component's `authorize` type, so it knows which type of control you want to use.

Then you can pop this into your controllers. Generally you want the pages controller to be allowed, to allow you to serve a homepage.

```
function beforeFilter() {
  $this->Auth->allow('index','view');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Router::connect('/', array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'login'));

Will make site.com/ the login page, not a good idea IMO.